# When I call a method inside a class it is not working but it works outside?

Tags: python

```
def lookup_cell(self, column, row):
    return(self.puzzle[row-1][column-1])

def lookup_column(self, column):
    output = []
    for i in range(9):
        output.append(self.lookup_cell(column, i+1))
    return output

def check_puzzle(self):
    valid = True
    #check all the rows
    for i in range(1,10):
        row = self.lookup_row(i)
        while 0 in row: row.remove(0)
        for i in range(1,10):
            if row.count(i) > 1:
                valid = False

    #check all the columns
    for i in range(1,10):
        print(i)
        print(easy.lookup_column(i))

puzzle = '''0,9,0,7,5,1,0,2,3 /n
       2,1,8,6,0,3,7,5,4 /n
       0,0,0,4,0,2,0,0,0 /n
       1,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,2 /n
       0,0,0,5,0,0,3,8,0 /n
       3,0,0,8,2,0,5,0,6 /n
       0,0,0,0,7,0,0,4,8 /n
       0,4,9,0,0,0,0,7,0 /n
       0,2,0,0,0,5,6,3,1 '''

easy = Sudoku(puzzle)
```

Here the code works and prints the columns of the puzzle properly:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(easy.lookup_column(i))
```

when this runs I get an error which I'll add below:

```
easy.check_puzzle()
```

```
1 [9, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 7, 4, 2] 2 [7, 1, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5] 3 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/Users/ellis/Desktop/Sudoku.py", line 121, in <module>
    easy.check_puzzle()   
File "/Users/ellis/Desktop/Sudoku.py", line 81, in check_puzzle
    print(easy.lookup_column(i))   
File "/Users/ellis/Desktop/Sudoku.py", line 65, in lookup_column
    output.append(self.lookup_cell(column, i+1))   
File "/Users/ellis/Desktop/Sudoku.py", line 19, in lookup_cell
    return(self.puzzle[row-1][column-1]) 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Try to replace `print(easy.lookup_column(i))` with `print(self.lookup_column(i))`.

Comment: Please see the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) section in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). There are lots of parts of the code missing so we can test your code and help you properly. Just to name a few: there is not a class in your code; no implementation of `lookup_row` method

Answer (score 0):

Your code works outside of the class method because

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(easy.lookup_column(i))
```

is not calling

```
def lookup_cell(self, column, row):
    return(self.puzzle[row-1][column-1]
```

The traceback you posted shows that the code above is causing the issue, where your accessing values in the object that's outside its bounds

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but why not use a list for puzzle instead of a string?

Try this:

```
class Sudoku(object):
    def __init__(self,puzzle):
        self.puzzle = puzzle
        print("Inside class; column lookup")
        for i in range(1,10):
            print('Column {0} ='.format(i),self.lookup_column(i))
        self.check_puzzle()

    def lookup_cell(self, column, row):
        return self.puzzle[row-1][column-1]

    def lookup_row(self,row):
        output = []
        for i in range(9):
            output.append(self.lookup_cell(i+1, row))
        return output

    def lookup_column(self, column):
        output = []
        for i in range(9):
            output.append(self.lookup_cell(column, i+1))
        return output

    def check_puzzle(self):
        valid = True
        #check all the rows
        for i in range(1,10):
            row = self.lookup_row(i)
            while 0 in row: row.remove(0)
            for i in range(1,10):
                if row.count(i) > 1:
                    valid = False

puzzle = [
        [0,9,0,7,5,1,0,2,3],
        [2,1,8,6,0,3,7,5,4],
        [0,0,0,4,0,2,0,0,0],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,2],
        [0,0,0,5,0,0,3,8,0],
        [3,0,0,8,2,0,5,0,6],
        [0,0,0,0,7,0,0,4,8],
        [0,4,9,0,0,0,0,7,0],
        [0,2,0,0,0,5,6,3,1]]

easy = Sudoku(puzzle)
print("Outside class; column lookup")
for i in range(1,10):
    print('Column {0} ='.format(i),easy.lookup_column(i))
easy.check_puzzle()
```